# Can't boot into 7.0 Nougat in VMware Fusion

Tags: 7.0-nougat, vmware

I followed [these instructions](https://www.tactig.com/install-android-nougat-vmware/) on *how to Install Android 7.0 Nougat on VMware*.

I am using VMware Fusion on a Mac.

I've found little difference between VMware Fusion and the instructions provided.

I can boot into grub, and select the OS (note: this is not a screenshot from my Mac):
[image]

but after I select the first Android entry, I receive the following:

[image]

where the cursor blinks and nothing else happens.

If I reboot, and select (Debug mode) from the OS selection screen, I get to the following, and no further:

[image]

If I reboot and choose (debug nomodeset), I reach the same place.

Same happens when selecting (Debug video=LVDS-1:d).

I run Windows 10, and Ubuntu through VMware Fusion fine.

Troubleshooting advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments on the page you linked already contain some helpful suggestions from people who had the same problem with those instructions. Nigel Christiaans suggested enabling 3D acceleration in VMWare's settings, and several visitors reported that this got them past the same root prompt you're stuck at. Robert further suggests that you should choose "Ubuntu" instead of "FreeBSD" when you create the VM.

Comment: Thanks Dan! Changing from `FreeBSD` to `Ubuntu` fixed the problem.